# Stopping a timed thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to stop a thread in python when the main script is killed. But since the thread is started hourly how do i stop the thread immediately?

```
def interval():
    ###the actual work being done here###
    try:
        threading.Timer(3600, interval).start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print "Exiting"
        cleanup_stop_interval();
        sys.exit()
interval()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using `sched.scheduler` instead of `threading.Timer` here. There are some differences to be aware of:

- `sched.scheduler` runs everything in the main process, not in
  threads.
- If the current process takes longer than `delay` seconds, the
  scheduled event will start *after* the current call to `interval`
  completes. `threading.Timer` works differently -- if the work done in
  `interval` takes longer than an hour, more than one thread would run
  `interval` concurrently.

I'm guessing you really do not want more than one `interval` to be running concurrently, so `sched.scheduler` may be more appropriate here than `threading.Timer`.

---

```
import timeit
import sched
import time
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG,
                    format = '%(threadName)s: %(asctime)s: %(message)s',
                    datefmt = '%H:%M:%S')
schedule = sched.scheduler(timeit.default_timer, time.sleep)
delay = 5 # change to 3600 to schedule event in 1 hour

def interval():
    logger.info('All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.')
    schedule.enter(delay = delay, priority = 1, action = interval, argument = ())
    # Uncomment this to see how scheduled events are delayed if interval takes a
    # long time. 
    # time.sleep(10) 

schedule.enter(delay = 0, priority = 1, action = interval, argument = ())
try:
    schedule.run()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print('Exiting')
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to kill a thread just like that, cause it could

- holding resources
- be a parent to other threads

proper way of handling this is to have an exit_request flag that each threads checks on regular interval to see if it is time for him to exit, and wait for it to exit by using `join()`

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop a thread from another thread.  What you probably want is to make the thread a daemon thread, meaning the process will exit even if the thread is still active:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon

> daemon
>
> A boolean value indicating whether this thread is a daemon thread (True) or not (False). This must be set before start() is called, otherwise RuntimeError is raised. Its initial value is inherited from the creating thread; the main thread is not a daemon thread and therefore all threads created in the main thread default to daemon = False.
>
> The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.

Note you could still have problems where the process ended in the middle of this thread doing its work.  If you want to protect against that, then have the thread wake up frequently to check if it should exit cleanly.